# Return Files Using Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project using django, the project is about a website that takes 2 file(user upload em) then the website return/sends back once the file is ready(user download em). Currently, this is what I have in my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

import difflib
import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import FileForm
from .forms import UploadFileForm

# Create your views here.

def handle_uploaded_file(file1,file2):
     print(file1)
    # with open(file1, 'r') as t1, open(file2, 'r') as t2: # here i open 2 files and make python read it
    fileone = file1.readlines() # read lines from 1st file
    filetwo = file2.readlines() # read lines from 2nd file
    fileone =[line.decode("utf-8").strip() for line in fileone]
    filetwo =[line.decode("utf-8").strip() for line in filetwo]
    # print(fileone,filetwo)

    with open('difference.csv', 'w') as outFile: # create output file called with update.csv
        for line in filetwo : #for statement
            # print(line)
            if line not in fileone : # if line is not same
                print(line)
                outFile.write(line+"\n")

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.FILES)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("cool")
handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES.get('file1'),request.FILES.get('file2'))
                return HttpResponseRedirect('results/')
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'hello.html', {'form': form})



from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

def results(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type=smart_str(r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\PycharmProjects\mysite\difference.csv'))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str('difference.csv')
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\PycharmProjects\mysite\difference.csv')
    return response
```

I have been succesfully upload files and create the difference(difference.csv) just fine. However, once the difference.csv is created, the webpage does not send back the processed/file that is ready, it gives me "NameError at /file_diff/results/
name 'difference' is not defined" error

I know the problem lies in the results class but I cant get to it. Yes, my code is bad(im new and im still learning), if anyone here could help me out, that'd be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `results` function you use `difference.csv` without quotes, when you call `smart_str(difference.csv)`, try with quotes, because it is a file.

```
def results(request):
    ...
    smart_str('difference.csv')
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str('difference.csv')
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! It works, but when I open the difference.csv that I just downloaded, there is 0 record. When I open it manually in the folder that supposed to store it (pycharmprojects/djangoproject/difference.csv), I can see the differences 1000 records in 1 file. Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: try to give the absolute path to file for example `/home/user/project/difference.csv`

Comment: I edited my original answer and added absolute paths to the responses except in return response. However, i got SyntaxError: <unicode error> 'unicodeescape' in CMD and page isnt working in the browser. Is it because I didnt put it in the right response? I tried to put only one absolute path in only 1 response and tried each one of em but still doesnt work

Comment: try with `r` ( to produce raw string ), try this `smart_str(r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\PycharmProjects\mysite\difference.csv')`

Comment: I put your absolute path to response [X-Sendfile'], while it gives me a green light, but the record is still not there after i download it. Adding absolute path in response['Content-Disposition'] only rename the file same as the absolute path. I didnt put your absolute path in response = HttpResponse because I believe it just pushes the file out, I might be wrong. Could you point out where shall I add the absolute path to exactly?